# How can I make WebStorm adjust the indentation of closing tags to match their parent when using JSX Harmony?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jsx

I'm attempting to switch from Visual Studio 2015 to IntelliJ WebStorm 10.0.4.

After some Googling, I found I needed to switch the JavaScript language to JSX Harmony in order to get JSX syntax to work.

Now, I'm finding that the indentation of closing tags is becoming a real pain.

For example, if I write the following, when I go to close the `<div>` tag, it puts it on the next line at an indented level. That's fine, but I expect that once I complete the tag, it would auto adjust to the same indentation level as its matching opening tag. This is the behavior in Visual Studio 2015.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                </div> //The indentation is wrong here after completing the tag.
        );
    }
});

module.exports = MyComponent;
```

[image]

I know I can do Reformat Code with <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> but I don't want to have to do that all the time.

I've tried with JSLint and JSHint on and off, but they don't seem to support JSX very well. I've also tried with ESLint, but it seems a little buggy, and, also, doesn't solve this problem (should it?).

Have I configured something incorrectly?
Is there a way to configure this behavior in WebStorm?

Comment: This actually stopped me from upgrading and using webstorm for my react work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 solutions:

The simple way is to enter `<div`, then the IDE will show you the options. You select the "div" word, and that's done.

The other way is to generate a "Live template" in the WebStorm preferences. You can use a snippet instead of typing that much. You may also Google "how to use a live template" later.